# Show initial value of bootstrap slider in a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I use this [Bootstrap-Slider library](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) and I have an issue. I want to show the value of the slider in a span next to the bar. At the moment, I handle to do it only when the slider change but not when the window load for the first time with it's initial values.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <span style="float:left;">Age</span>
   <span style="float:right;"><span id="ageval"></span></span>
   <input id="age" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="int" data-slider-min="5" data-slider-max="55" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="{{age}}" value="{{age}}"/>
</div>

$('#age').slider({
      tooltip: 'hide'
})
$('#age').on('slide', function(slideEvt) {
      $("#ageval").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `slider.value`

```
$("#ageval").html($("#age).slider().value);
or
$("#ageval").html($("#age").slider("getValue"));
```

Comment: This doesn't help and actually it stops to update even on slide :(

Comment: are you using angular???, you got the starting value under your nose rigth in `value="{{age}}"`
i strongly advice you not to use jquery if you are using angular or any MVC plugin.
i dindt scrolled to se the value before couse you where asking for it

Comment: No. I don't think so. I don't even know what is this, so I don't believe that I use it :P